# Cassandra + GeoMesa: How to insert Point coordinate data?

Tags: geomesa

I want to insert GeoMesa compatible GIS data into my Cassandra database. How can I achieve this?

1. Create a table with a point type column
2. Insert some table data with a point coordinate

```
user@ubuntu: /var/log/cassandra$ cqlsh
Connected to Test Cluster at 127.0.0.1:9042
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.0.29 | CQL spec 3.4.0 | Native protocol v4]
Use HELP for help
cqlsh> CREATE KEYSPACE geomesa WITH REPLICATION = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy'. 'replication_factor': 3};
cqlsh> use geomesa;
cqlsh:geomesa> CREATE TABLE test (point 'Point');
SyntaxException: Error setting type Point: Unable to find abstract-type class 'org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.Point'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `cqlsh`, you'll need to interact with Cassandra using Java and the [GeoTools API](https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/stable/user/geotools.html). GeoMesa also provides [command-line tools](https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/stable/user/cassandra/commandline.html) which can be used to [ingest data](https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/stable/user/cli/ingest.html#ingest) without writing any code. You may also consider using [Apache NiFi](https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/stable/user/nifi/index.html) or [Apache Spark](https://www.geomesa.org/documentation/stable/user/spark/providers.html#geotools-rdd-provider).

Comment: Thanks! I will look into the documentation of how to ingest data using the command-line tools. Also a bonus question of interest, since I know you are involved in the GeoMesa project :) Is it on the roadmap that GeoMesa will support higher versions than Java 8 in the near future?

Comment: GeoMesa works with Java 8, 11 or 17. It sill builds with Java 8, but I don't think that prevents anyone from using it with a more recent version?